# iPhone open default application for file type

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, file-association

I am writing an app that will be downloading user's documents from a remote source. once my app has this document I want to open it in the default application. (.PDF) In android it was simple, but I cant seem to find any resources for iPhone.

How do I open the default application with the file?

**EDIT**
The file on the remote source is not a url. it needs to be downloaded through a web-service. I will either be saving the file to disk or trying to open it from memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`UIDocumentInteractionController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html). Read [`this guide`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010403) as well for more information.

Comment: @TomFobear could you please share some samples related this